# What does 'operator sockaddr *()'mean here?

Tags: c++

What does 'operator sockaddr *()'mean here ?
The class Raw is an inner class, sockaddr is a struct.

```cpp
struct sockaddr
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];       /* Address data.  */
  };
```

```cpp
class Address {
  public:
    //! \brief Wrapper around [sockaddr_storage](@ref man7::socket).
    //! \details A `sockaddr_storage` is enough space to store any socket address (IPv4 or IPv6).
    class Raw {
      public:
        sockaddr_storage storage{};  //!< The wrapped struct itself.
        operator sockaddr *();    // here
        operator const sockaddr *() const;
    };

  private:
    socklen_t _size;  //!< Size of the wrapped address.
    Raw _address{};   //!< A wrapped [sockaddr_storage](@ref man7::socket) containing the address.
.....
.....
```

Comment: It makes a user supplied conversion so you can `sockaddr *X = Address::Raw();` or `sockaddr *X = Address()._address();`

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators ? Especially the part on "operator *type* (2)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [user defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). An object of type `Raw` can implicitly be converted to a `sockaddr` pointer. For example the following will compile:

```
void fun(sockaddr *p); // function that takes a sockaddr pointer

Address::Raw r;
fun(r); // implicit conversion occurs from Raw in order to use function `fun`
```